# My state object is oneOfType

Tags: reactjs, react-proptypes

My component is `rendered` based on conditions before (a `fetch`). So the whole state object is set to either `{error:'blah'}` OR `{ok:PropTypes.string}`

I tried to do this:

```
const Body = ()=>{}

Body.propTypes = PropTypes.oneOfType([
  PropTypes.shape({error:PropTypes.string}),
  PropTypes.shape({ok:PropTypes.string})
]);
```

However this keeps giving me the error:

> Warning: Failed prop type: The prop isRequired is marked as required
>   in Body, but its value is undefined.

Is the only way to accomplish the above to set this into a single key in the state object? Like this:

```
Body.propTypes = {
  blah: PropTypes.oneOfType([
     PropTypes.shape({error:PropTypes.string}),
     PropTypes.shape({ok:PropTypes.string})
  ]);
}
```

Comment: What are the properties and its object structure?

Comment: The error is related to BodyManage - but in the code i see Body component. Am i missing something here ?

Comment: Oops @ArshabhAgarwal excuse that, fixed it up.

Comment: The second snippet is correct. The first one does not make sense